# Transform the discrete system $x[k+1] = (1-a)\cdot x_{\infty} +a\cdot x[k]$ to Continuous system

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Can anyone tell the continuous form of the discrete system given by:

\begin{equation}
x[k+1] = (1-a)\cdot x_{\infty} +a\cdot x[k]
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem, observe

$$\begin{cases}
x[k+1] - a~x[k] = (1 - a)x_\infty \\
x[k] - a~x[k-1] = (1 - a)x_\infty \\
\end{cases}$$

implies that

$$x[k+1] = (a + 1)~x[k] - a~x[k-1] $$

Or that

$$\begin{bmatrix} x[k+1] \\ x[k] \end{bmatrix} = \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} a + 1 & -a \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}}_M\begin{bmatrix} x[k] \\ x[k - 1] \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix} x[k+1] \\ x[k] \end{bmatrix} = M^k\begin{bmatrix} x[1] \\ x[0] \end{bmatrix}$$

Since the eigenvalues of $M$ are $a$ and $1$, the sequence converges only when $-1 < a \le 1$ or $x[0] = 0$.

Diagonalizing $M$:

$$M = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ a^{-1} & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ a^{-1} & 1 \end{bmatrix}^{-1}$$

Plugging that in and expanding the matrices:

$$\begin{bmatrix} x[k+1] \\ x[k] \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{(x[1] - x[0])a^{n+1} + x[0] a - x[1]}{a - 1} \\ \frac{(x[1] - x[0])a^{n} + x[0] a - x[1]}{a - 1} \end{bmatrix}$$

And adding that $x[1] = a~x[0] + (1 - a)x_\infty$ and simplifying:

$$x[k] = x_\infty(1 - a^{n}) + x[0]a^n$$

Comment: Interesting, but how do you get the convergence condition?

Comment: When is $a^\infty \ne \infty$ ?

Comment: yes but i suppose this is related to the $M^k$ isn't it? can you please direct me to the convergence theorem ?

Answer (score 1):

Subtract $x(k)$ from both sides:
$$x(k+1)-x(k)=(1-a)x_{\infty}+(a-1)x(k)=(1-a)(x_\infty-x(k))$$
$x(k+1)-x(k)$ is a discrete version of continuous derivative, so the continuous version of the above discrete system is:
$$x'(k)=(a-1)(x(k)-x_\infty)$$
and its solution is
$$x(k)=x_\infty+(x_0-x_\infty)e^{(a-1)k}$$
Similarly, solution to the original discrete system is
$$x[k]=x_\infty+(x_0-x_\infty)a^k$$

Comment: is this for a $\Delta T = 1$ ?

Comment: @use for $\Delta T=(k+1)-k=1$.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you mean with "transform to continuous" system, but I assume you mean "to transform the discrete-time system into a continuous-time system".

Then, it is impossible to convert a discrete-time system into a continuous time system because you don't know what happens between the sampling instants.

However, given that, you perhaps aim at finding a linear time-invariant system such that its exact discretization provides the system under exam.

For doing that, reverse the problem. Start with a continuous-time response and sets its parameters such that for a given sampling interval it matches your system.

To be more precise, given a continuous-time system of the form $\dot x(t)=a_cx(t)+b_cx_{\infty}$ (I assume $x_{\infty}$ to be constant), it is well-known that the solution is

\begin{align}
x(t)&=e^{a_c(t-t_0)}x(t_0)+\int_{t_0}^{t}e^{a_c(t-\tau)}b_cx_{\infty}d\tau \\ &=e^{a_c(t-t_0)}x(t_0)-\frac{b_c}{a_c}x_{\infty}(e^{a_c(t-t_0)}-1).
\end{align}
By taking $T$ as sampling period, you have 
$$
x((k+1)T)=\underbrace{e^{a_cT}}_{a}x(kT)\underbrace{-\frac{b_c}{a_c}(e^{a_cT}-1)}_{(1-a)}x_{\infty}.
$$
You basically have your initial system
$$
x[k+1]=(1-a)x_{\infty}+ax[k]
$$
Now you know know the relationship between the continuous and discrete-time systems parameters.